# How to add a wait time before hover function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, settimeout, jquery-hover

I am working on a nested menu, and when my mouse move over a option, a sublist will show up.
Here is my hover function:

```
$( ".sublist" ).parent().hover( function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("li_hover",300); //use to change the background color
    $(this).find(".sublist").toggle("slide", {}, 500); //sub list show / hide
});
```

Now, I want add a short period before the sublist shows up to prevent the crazy mouse moving from user. Does somebody have a good suggestion on this?

---

Update:

Thanks for you guys, I did a little bit change on my program, recently it looks like this:

```
function doSomething_hover (ele) {
    ele.toggleClass("li_hover",300);
    ele.find(".sublist").toggle("slide", {}, 500);
}

$(function () {
    $( ".sublist" ).parent().hover( function () {
        setTimeout(doSomething_hover($(this)), 3000);
    });
}):
```

This is weird that setTimeout will not delay anything. but if I change the function call to `doSomething_hover` (without "()"), the function will delay good. but i can not pass any jquery element to the function, so it still not works, could somebody tell me that how to make `doSomething_hover($(this))` work in `setTimeout` ?

---

Update 2:
Got the setTimeout work, but it seems not what I want:
What I exactly want is nothing will happen, if the mouse hover on a option less than 0.5sec.

Anyway, here is the code I make setTimeout work:

```
function doSomething_hover (ele) {
    ele.toggleClass("li_hover",300);
    ele.find(".sublist").toggle("slide", {}, 500);
}

$(function () {
    $( ".sublist" ).parent().hover( function () {
        var e = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () { doSomething_hover(e); }, 1000);
    });
}):
```

---

Final Update:
I got this work by using clearTimeout when I move the mouse out.
so the code should be:

```
    $( ".sublist" ).parent().mouseover( function () {
        var e = $(this);
        this.timer = setTimeout(function () { doSomething_hover(e); }, 500);
    });

    $( ".sublist" ).parent().mouseout ( function () {
        if(this.timer){
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("li_hover")){
            $(this).toggleClass("li_hover");
        }
        $(this).find(".sublist").hide("slide", {}, 500);

    });
```

This is the part in the `$(document).ready()`. Other code will be same as above.

---

真. Final Update:
So, `mouseover` and `mouseout` will lead to a bug sometime, since when I move the mouse to the sublist, the parents' `mouseover` event will be fire, and hide the sublist.
Problem could be solved by using `hover` function:

```
    $( ".sublist" ).parent().hover( 
        function () {
            var e = $(this);
            this.timer = setTimeout(function () { doSomething_hover(e); }, 500);
        },
        function () {
            if(this.timer){
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
            }
            $(this).find(".sublist").hide("slide", {}, 500);
            if($(this).hasClass("li_hover")){
                $(this).toggleClass("li_hover",300);
            }
        }
    );
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please:

**Code**

```
setInterval(doSomthing_hover, 1000);


function doSomthing_hover() {
    $(".sublist").parent().hover(function() {

        $(this).toggleClass("li_hover", 300); //use to change the background color
        $(this).find(".sublist").toggle("slide", {}, 500); //sub list show / hide
    });

}​
```

**SetTime vs setInterval**

At a fundamental level it's important to understand how JavaScript timers work. Often times they behave unintuitively because of the single thread which they are in. Let's start by examining the three functions to which we have access that can construct and manipulate timers.

var id = `setTimeout(fn, delay);` - Initiates a single timer which will call the specified function after the delay. The function returns a unique ID with which the timer can be canceled at a later time.

var id = `setInterval(fn, delay);` - Similar to setTimeout but continually calls the function (with a delay every time) until it is canceled.

`clearInterval(id);`, `clearTimeout(id);` - Accepts a timer ID (returned by either of the aforementioned functions) and stops the timer callback from occurring.

In order to understand how the timers work internally there's one important concept that needs to be explored: timer delay is not guaranteed. Since all JavaScript in a browser executes on a single thread asynchronous events (such as mouse clicks and timers) are only run when there's been an opening in the execution.

*Further read this:* http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried your solution, but the sublist will not show too, but if I change the functions in doSomething_hover() to alert("hello"), it works pretty good. Do you know something about that?

Comment: I think this logic will be: bind the function to the hover event after 1 sec?

Answer (score 2):

```
timeout = setTimeout('timeout_trigger()', 3000);
clearTimeout(timeout);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//hide a div after 3 seconds
setTimeout( "jQuery('#div').hide();",3000 );
});
```

refer   [link](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/)

```
function hover () {
$( ".sublist" ).parent().hover( function () {
$(this).toggleClass("li_hover",300); //use to change the background color
$(this).find(".sublist").toggle("slide", {}, 500); //sub list show / hide
});
}
setTimeout( hover,3000 );
```

....

Comment: +1 to you as well `:)` your second example is wrong see my sample below which you have updated anyhoo +1 it should be like this: `setTimeout( hover,3000 );`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.setTimeout`

```
$(".sublist").parent().hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("li_hover", 300); //use to change the background color
        $(this).find(".sublist").toggle("slide", {}, 500); //sub list show / hide
    }, 1000);
});​
```